# Javadocs for JAX-RS services

Tags: java, jax-rs, javadoc

The JAX-RS annotations Path, GET, POST, PUT and DELETE do not have @Documented on them, so they do not appear in javadocs. It would be extremely useful for these annotations to appear in javadocs, because they would tell you the path and HTTP method for the call. Anybody know how to get this information to appear in javadocs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the RESTful part is outside the scope of javadoc. What you are describing is usually handled by a WADL. [Jax-rs includes support for generating WADL's](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html). The reason is non Java code may want to consume your Web Service, so a non Java based specification is preferable.